# How to tell python I need the decimals?

Tags: python, nltk

My program is to find the number of types, the number of tokens, and the type-to-token ratio. However, I don't know how to tell Python the answer to ttr is not an integer.

```
from nltk.corpus import inaugural 

print inaugural.fileids()

tokens = inaugural.words("1789-Washington.txt")

numtokens = len(tokens)
print numtokens

types = sorted(set(tokens))
numtypes = len(types)
print numtypes

# This is the part I'm unsure about.     
ttr = numtypes/numtokens
print ttr
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in Python 3, the division operator `/` is performing floating point division by default:

```
>>> 3 / 2
1.5
>>> 4 / 2
2.0
```

since integer division is handled by the `//` operator.

In Python 2.x, if you want decimal accuracy in integer division, you can convert either the nominator or the denominator to `float()`, like this:

```
ttf = float(numtypes) / numtokens
```

Alternatively, as tobias_k points out, you can do

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 3 / 2
1.5
```

to get Python3-esque division in Python 2.x

Comment: Or `from __future__ import division`

Comment: the float ( ) method worked for my python 2. Thank you for the prompt reply!